# Excel VBA - Make a HTTP request with proxy

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a HTTP request using VBA in Excel in my office but it does not work. My office network uses a proxy to connect to the internet so http requests do not go directly to the URL requested.

I tried the following code (code to connect without proxy) at home without a proxy and it works perfectly.

When I set the proxy in the code (see code to connect via a proxy server) and I run it in my office, it always times out without reaching the requested page.
Would you be able to tell me where my code is wrong and how to fix it.
Please note my office network uses a PAC file which I was able to download and which includes the function FindProxyForURL(url, host). I got the proxy server address from there.

```
'Code to connect without proxy

Dim WHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Set WHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
WHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False
WHTTP.Send
x = WHTTP.ResponseText
Debug.Print x


'Code to connect via a proxy server

Dim WHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
Dim proxy As String

Set WHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
proxy = "myoffice_proxy_IP:80"
WHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com", False
WHTTP.SetProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, proxy, ""
WHTTP.Send
x = WHTTP.ResponseText
Debug.Print x
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I only managed to get a timeout with this if I did not define your constant HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY. As long as this variable is defined as LONG and has a value it works. If you actually have this defined somewhere else I would guess the problem lies within your proxy server and how it handles bad requests

Comment: Hi Chrowno, I don't understand your answer. HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY is one of the constant options for the method SetProxy and as such I don't think it requires declaration. Anyway I tried to declare it as long but the script still times out. Maybe I am using the wrong IP for the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY` is a constant a you have to define it. For example, this is all the values that `WHTTP.SetProxy` command can accept:

```
HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_DEFAULT   = 0
HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PRECONFIG = 0
HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_DIRECT    = 1
HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY     = 2
```